# When to close and when to delete a question?

Tags: discussion

I made a question on Stackoverflow and it ended up being a mess with too many problems for me to bother to salvage it, but people responded with comments to it(no answers).

Should I close or delete questions like that?

Additionally I don't have enough reputation to even close my own question.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete it, if it has no upvotes and no upvoted answers.

Answer (score -2):

I would only delete my question if it has a -3 score or more, assuming it has already been revised to no avail.